# Calculate hours between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make this overview of "work" hours

However I can't get it to calculate the hours between two dates in my sql db, but it wont return the result.

I tried to just display the two SQL entries which worked, but it seems like the calculation wont use the SQL enteries

I am getting this error in the top of my page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (31/10-2012 19:14) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php:46 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php(46): DateTime->__construct('31/10-2012 19:1...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 46
```

What am I doing wrong here??

The thing I need help to is on line 43-52
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="xxxx";
$password="xxxx";
$db_name="xxxxx";
$tbl_name="log";


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


?>
<title>VT Log - Oversigt</title>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td width="30%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Navn</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Start</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Slut</strong></td>
<td width="30%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Kommentar</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Tid</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['user']; ?><BR></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['start']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['end']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
<?php
$stamp1 = $rows['start'];
$stamp2 = $rows['end'];
$date1 = new DateTime($stamp2);
$date2 = new DateTime($stamp2);
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);
$hours = $diff->h;
$hours = $hours + ($diff->d*24);
?>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $hours;?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><?php echo "Total arbejdstid: " . array_sum($numbers) . "\n Timer";?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Nothing returned? The wrong result? The right result, in the wrong place?

Comment: could let mysql do the work for you and use datediff() or timediff() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Sorry forgot the write whats the problem:
I tried to just display the two SQL entries which worked, but it seems like the calculation wont use the SQL enteries

Comment: Could it be caused by you initialising `$date1` and `$date2` to the same thing?

Comment: Dagon - It means "end" :-)

I am getting this error on my page: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (31/10-2012 19:14) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php:46 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php(46): DateTime->__construct('31/10-2012 19:1...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 46

Comment: nice. must remember that:-) would still use the easy mysql functions for this.

Comment: @Dagon, How can I use the mysql function for this?

Comment: select ... timediff(start,end) as dif ....

Comment: Read the error message carefully, it tells you what the problem is: What kind of date format is "31/10-2012 19:14" anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both dates to unix timestamps, then return the difference in hours.

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)) / 60.0 / 60.0 as hours_difference
```

No need for any PHP calculations after that...

Comment: or use  timediff() , no conversion needed

Comment: So I'd simply just need to parse that into a new SQL query and use the result from there?

Comment: Yes if that's your goal.  You can even use this SELECT as part of another query.  i.e SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE completed_hours > (SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)) / 60.0 / 60.0)

Comment: Good point Dagon - TIMEDIFF() works - no need to convert to timestamps first, but then you have to convert the resulting DATE object into hours.  Same difference... :)

Comment: Ryan, I did this and now I get this: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 36 .... Line 36: while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Comment: Can you show the full SQL query?  Also, take a look at mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id ASC > (SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)) / 60.0 / 60.0 as hours_difference";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18877/discussion-between-emil-elkjaer-nielsen-and-ryan-griggs)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$date1 = new DateTime($stamp2);
```

to this

```
 $date1 = new DateTime($stamp1);
```

Comment: I am still having this error at the top of my page: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (31/10-2012 19:14) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php:46 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php(46): DateTime->__construct('31/10-2012 19:1...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 46

Comment: $date1 = new DateTime($stamp1);

Comment: Seems like the DateTime function doesn't like the way your date string is formatted.  Why does the datetime have both slashes and dashes? is that the standard format for your location?

Comment: try this kind of manipulation and see $date1 = new DateTime(str_replace($stamp1, "/", "-"));

Comment: Would it work if I only use the dashes? The manipulation gave me this:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 43 - Line 43 is the $date1 = xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: sorry you have to add another additional bracket to end $date1 = new DateTime(str_replace($stamp1, "/", "-"));

Comment: I still get the error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (-) at position 0 (-): Unexpected character' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php:43 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php(43): DateTime->__construct('-') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 43

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Many thanks Ryan Griggs

Change SQL query to `$sql="SELECT *, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)) / 60.0 / 60.0 as hours_difference FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id ASC";`

Replace

```
<?php
$stamp1 = $rows['start'];
$stamp2 = $rows['end'];
$date1 = new DateTime($stamp2);
$date2 = new DateTime($stamp2);
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);
$hours = $diff->h;
$hours = $hours + ($diff->d*24);
?>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $hours;?></td>
```

with

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?$var = number_format($rows['hours_difference'],2);
$var = number_format($var,1);
echo $var; ?></td>
```